# Is my offline local repository broken?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I have created a offline local repository with apt-mirror.  I followed the instructions here:  [tecmint.com/setup-local-repositories-in-ubuntu](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-local-repositories-in-ubuntu/).
After I finished modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I ran `apt-get update` and I received this error message:

```
File not found - /usr/local/repo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch file:/usr/local/repo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages File not found - /usr/local/repo/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages (2: No such file or directory)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can I ignore that error?  I'm on a 64-but machine.  Do I need 32-bit files?

I followed all instructions, but when I did an `apt-get upgrade`, no new packages were upgraded.  Is something broke?  How can I tell if my offline repository actual works?  How can I figure out what is wrong with my repository?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to solve this.  The problem is a combination of two things

- apt-mirror is not downloading deb files for the i386 architecture
  (I'm running this on a 64-bit CPU)
- 'apt-get update' expects the i386 files to exist (or at least the
  i-386 Packages)

So, my solution is to simply force apt-mirror to download the i-386 files (in addition to the amd64 files).  Previously, the /etc/apt/mirror.list file contained entries like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

For each of those, I changed them to

```
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

as well as a line for the i-386 files:

```
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

I then ran 'apt-get update' with no error messages.